# Does French make use of the historical present?

Tags: temps-grammatical

Let's say you are telling a story using past narration. Is it common to use the historical present in order to make an event more vivid?

An example might be,

> Malheureusement, le vol était complet. J'ai demandé tous les gens à la porte pour leur billet. Finalement, un fil me donne son billet gratuitement.

In this example, the last sentence uses the present tense, even though it is narrating an event in the past. Is this a common technique in French?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the historical present can be used that way in French too.

I tried to rephrase the last sentences but cannot make sense about *fil* (thread/wire?).

> *J'ai demandé à tous les gens présents à la porte d'embarquement s'ils pouvaient me procurer un billet. Finalement, un ??? m'offre son billet gratuitement.*

Note that *donner gratuitement* is avoided being a pleonasm, but *offrir gratuitement* is not.

Comment: I meant to say "boy" (garçon?) He was an adolescent of maybe 16 or 17 years. I would actually be interested to know what word you would use to describe an adolescent male of this age.

Comment: Ha, you meant *fils*. You can use *un jeune homme* or *un garçon*.

Comment: Would *fils* be the wrong word? Is that reserved for a child?

Comment: Yes *fils* would be very odd here.

Comment: @ktm5124 "Fils" only means "son", and can't be used without a relation to a parent (as opposed to "*fille*" that means both "girl" and "daughter")

Comment: Thanks, @TeleportingGoat. (Wow, that's fun to say!!) I would not have known that point about fils.